# how to bring linux bridge up at booting time?

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, upstart, network-bridge

I am trying to bring up a linux bridge at the time my ubuntu is booting.
The bridge is mapped to eth0 interface. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by editing the rc.local file:

> sudo nano /etc/rc.local

and adding the command used to bring up the bridge, to the bottom of the file before the `exit 0` command (if present):

> ifup eth0

The rc.local file is executed at the time of booting the system, so any commands within the file will be executed at that time.

Comment: okay, but I want to check the status of the bridge whether up or down and do the corresponding change(up/down) to the bridge. How can this br done through a script at the time of booting?

Comment: @MickStJohn09 So, by "And do the corresponding change(up/down)" do you mean that if the bridge is up at booting time, you would like to take it down? I don't know if that makes any sense? The answer I posted will bring up the bridge at boot time if it is down, or keep it up if it is already up.if you would like the bring it down you can use the command 'ifdown eth0' or to check the status of the bridge you can use 'ifconfig'